# I need the right range to use in my for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to print out a table of values telling how many months a scientist can keep having rabbits reproduce before they run out of cages. I can't figure out what range to use in my for loop. I need it to stop once the total pairs of rabbits exceeds the number of cages that is input. Heres what I have:

```
cages = int(input("How many cages do you have? "))

print("Month\t", "Adults\t", "Babies\t", "Total")

def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
n = 1

total = fib(n+2)
adults = fib(n+1)
babies = fib(n)
if total < cages:
    ## dont know what to put in range here to make the loop stop at the 
    ## correct place
    for n in range(cages):
        print((n+1),  "\t", fib(n + 1), "\t", fib(n), "\t", fib(n+2))

print("You ran out of cages!")
```

"cages" doesn't seem to be the right range because then the total gets way larger than the number of cages.

Comment: You don't want a `for` loop; you want a `while` loop that manually increments `n`, exiting when `n` is less than `fib(n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is `break`. Try something like this

```
for n in range(cages):
     total = fib(n+2)
     adults = fib(n+1)
     babies = fib(n)
     if total > cages:
          break

     print((n+1),  "\t", fib(n + 1), "\t", fib(n), "\t", fib(n+2))
```